# I used some problems in using pyspark on jupyter

Tags: pyspark

The problem that occurs when I load the file。

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import NaiveBayes  
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator 
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
         .appName("Mytest") \
         .config("spark.some.config.option","some-value") \
         .getOrCreate()
# Load training data  
data = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("/test/test.txt")
```

Comment: Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-56723b0238d6> in <module>()
      6 spark = SparkSession.builder          .appName("Mytest")          .config("spark.some.config.option","some-value")          .getOrCreate()
      7 # Load training data
----> 8 data = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("/test/test.txt")
      9 # Split the data into train and test
     10 splits = data.randomSplit([0.6, 0.4], 1234)

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o323.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 14, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,0"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:284)

Comment: Please append codes in your comments to your post.